# Check url before redirect symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes

```
if ($u = $this->generateUrl('_'.$specific.'_thanks'))
  return $this->redirect($u);
else
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_thanks'));
```

I wan't to redirect to the `_specific_thanks` url when it exist. So How to check if a url exist?

When I did that, I had this error:

> Route "_specific_thanks" does not exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to check if a route exists. But you can look for route existence through the router service.

```
$router = $this->container->get('router');
```

You can then get a route collection and call `get()` for a given route, which returns null if it doesn't exist.

```
$router->getRouteCollection()->get('_'. $specific. '_thanks');
```

Comment: Perfect it's working for me! Just `$this->container->get('router');` with symfony 2.1.4

Comment: Great! I updated the answer so that it fits sf 2.1.4 :) $this->get('router') also works I think.

Answer (score 9):

Using `getRouteCollection()` on runtime is *not the correct solution*. Executing this method will require the cache to be rebuilt. This means that routing cache will be rebuilt on *each* request, making your app much slower than needed.

If you want to check whether a route exists or not, use the try ... catch construct:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;

try {
    dump($router->generate('some_route'));
} catch (RouteNotFoundException $e) {
    dump('Oh noes, route "some_route" doesn't exists!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, check the route exists in the array of all routes:

```
    $router = $this->get('router');

    if (array_key_exists('_'.$specific.'_thanks',$router->getRouteCollection->all())){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_'.$specific.'_thanks'))
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_thanks'));
    }
```

Comment: Just too fast. But instead of `in_array('',array_keys())` You could just do `if (array_key_exists('_'.$specific.'_thanks',$router->getRouteCollection()->all())`

Comment: @AlainTiemblo I am not sure it is really a performance killer, @ahmedSiouani's solution is neater but the code does almost the same thing, just `isset` rather than `array_key_exists`. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L93 for how `all` works.   The real performance killer is `getRouteCollection` as it loads the routes if they are not already loaded.  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php#L190 this has caused us some real performance issues in a project :)

Comment: Yeah I agree that `getRouteCollection` is the most costy thing here, but `->all()` does return every route in an array, if your website is large, translate routes according to locales and whatever else, this will be a large array and costy in memory/slowness. By the way, I hope large websites will never need to use such tricks :).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check  your cast? 
And  are you sure about the route? usually  route start with

```
'WEBSITENAME_'.$specific.'_thanks'
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
if ($u == $this->generateUrl('_'.$specific.'_thanks') )
```

Comment: I really don't know how this can solve the problem... Did you really understand the code?

Comment: I have no experience with symfony2. I saw inside if condition he put an assignment, so I thought it may be the problem. I don't know what $this->generateUrl() function returns.

Comment: Did you see that the assignment is used inside the condition? So using `===` remove the assignment...