# Test if route exists in Twig Template (Symfony 2)

Tags: exception, symfony, path, twig, routes

I want to generate a Navigation from my Database where I store the names of my routes as link targets. 
My Controller simply gets all necessary navigation entries from the database and returns the rows which are used directly in my twig template.

```
/**
* @Route("/")
* @Template()
*/
public function myAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $navi = $em->getRepository('myBundle:Navigation')->findAll();
    return array("navi" => $navi);
}
```

Thus there is the possibility that a route does not exist which results in Error 500.

I need a method to check wether a named route exists or not. I tried to test it with `{% if path('routeName') is defined %} ... {% endif %}` but this does not work.

AFAIK my Controller could catch Twig Exceptions but I just want twig to *ignore* navigation entries which are not valid. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check url before redirect symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136484/check-url-before-redirect-symfony2)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make a custom twig function (check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) link for more information). Function that checks is the given name a valid route:

```
function routeExists($name)
{
    // I assume that you have a link to the container in your twig extension class
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    return (null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name)) ? false : true;
}
```

But I'm not sure it's a good idea to handle navigation in such way (in database). Maybe you'd better use something else?

Comment: Thanks, now it works! That helped me a lot. Caching the navigation entries to take the load off the database will be the next step.

Comment: `return null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name);` is good enough. :)

Comment: @HelpNeeder I'd say `return null !== $router-> ...` :)

Comment: According to that comment it's better to catch the exeption like @imanali example : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6710